# How i change content $OUTPUT->navigation_menu();

Tags: php, moodle

How to change the contents of this output??

I'm trying to change , but can not find the file q make this change

$OUTPUT->navigation_menu();

in BCU theme

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse ">
<?php echo $OUTPUT->navigation_menu(); ?>
<?php echo $OUTPUT->custom_menu(); ?>
<?php echo $OUTPUT->tools_menu(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of Moodle is this?

Comment: That function doesn't exist in Moodle 3.0.2 - can you check the name of the function? Or post the html content that you want to change.

Comment: in the BCU theme /includes/header.php, i edit the post with content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function navigation_menu()` is in `/theme/bcu/renderers.php` - its not a standard Moodle function but included in the BCU theme renderer.

https://bitbucket.org/bcu/moodle-theme_bcu/src/e8a1b8ca625843c740c31466a56fbaf89c3143bd/renderers.php?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Answer (score 1):

shot in the dark here.. maybe..

```
ob_start();
$OUTPUT->navigation_menu();
$output = ob_get_clean();

// do stuff to change $output

echo $output;
```

Comment: I can not change , just want to know where is the settings for this output , because I need to change the html tag , you understand?